# How to add subdomain to the URL conditionally in ASP .NET Core?

Tags: asp.net-core, url-rewriting, subdomain, middleware, multi-tenant

Im am trying to develop a middleware that modifies the system URL with a subdomain.

The Scenario was, Every user was assigned to the tenant. All the tenants have domain keys. When the application is started, the Login form appears, and it is based on the root URL(ex: abc.com). After the user logs in to the system, the URL needs to be modified with the tenant-associated domain (ex: lk.abc.com).

I tried to achieve this using middleware, But URL is not changed,

```
public class UrlRewriteMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public UrlRewriteMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context, ApplicationDbContext applicationDbContext, MtContext mtContext)
    {
        if (context.Request.GetDisplayUrl().GetSubDomain() == null)
        {
            // if user is authenticated, then we apply the necessary sub-domain for the current url
            if (context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                var userId = context.User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);


                var userTenantId = applicationDbContext.Users.FirstOrDefault(o => o.Id == Guid.Parse(userId));

                if (userTenantId == null)
                {
                    context.Request.Path = "/Identity/Account/Login";
                    await _next(context);
                    return;
                }

                var customer = mtContext.Customer.FirstOrDefault(o => o.Id == userTenantId.TenantId);

                if (customer == null)
                {
                    context.Request.Path = "/Identity/Account/Login";
                    await _next(context);
                    return;
                }

                var subDomain = customer.DomainKey;

                context.Request.Host = new HostString($"{subDomain}.{context.Request.Host.Host}");

                await _next(context);
                return;
            }

            context.Response.Redirect("Identity/Account/Login");
            await _next(context);
        }

        await _next(context);
    }
}
```

The above code is not working because the URL is not modified with a subdomain.

Just I want to check the user authenticate states and modify the URL with a subdomain if already not applied the subdomain to the URL.

Please let me know any solution for this scenario.

Comment: Could you please tell me why you need to modify the `context.Request.Host`? If you want to let that user go to another domain, you could just rewrite or redirect that user to other subdomain. If you just want to add some property you could add some information into the httpcontext.

Comment: @BrandoZhang I want to change the root domain to a subdomain when the user logged in to the system. That's the requirement. If any way to do this instead of middleware it is also fine.

Comment: Do you allow the user to redirect or rewrite to another domain ?

Comment: @BrandoZhang no